# Get the total/sum of commission per user and display it

Tags: codeigniter

My target is to display the total commission per user. I tried it already but the only thing I'm getting is commission of myself which is 503,582.26. I want to display the commission dynamically. For example: ID 1 = 500, ID 2 = 300, ID = 600.  I have provided screenshot below for more explanation. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

[image]

Views:

```
<?php 
                               foreach($result as $rows) {   $uuid = $rows->uuid;
                               $userID = $rows->userID; ?>     
                                   <?php if($rows->uuid===$_SESSION['uid']): ?>     
                                <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->firstname; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->mobile; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->account_type; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->currentPoints; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php $sum = number_format($commBalance -$commWithdrawn,2); echo ($sum);?></td>
                                <td>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function agents()
    {
        $data['activeNav'] = "";
        $data['subnav'] = "networks";
        $this->header($data);
        $this->nav();
        $data['result'] = $this->networks->getAllData();
        $data['commBalance']=$this->load->networks->gettotalcommi();
        $data['commWithdrawn']=$this->load->networks->gettotalWithdrawn();
        $data['meronResult'] = $this->networks->meronBets();
        $data['walaResult'] = $this->networks->walaBets();
        $data['tagent']=$this->load->networks->gettotalagent();
        $this->load->view('agents', $data);
        $this->footer();
       
    }
```

**Model:**

```
 function gettotalcommi(){
            $reqcommi= $this->session->userdata('uid');
            $a = $this->input->post('userID');
            
            $this->db->select_sum('amount');
            $this->db->where('commTo',$reqcommi);
            
            $bind = array('commType', 'in');
            $this->db->where_in('commType', $bind);
            $result = $this->db->get('agent_commission_history')->row();
            
            return $result->amount;
        }
        function gettotalWithdrawn(){
            $a = $this->input->post('userID');
            $reqcommi= $this->session->userdata('uid');
            
            $this->db->select_sum('amount');
            $this->db->where('commTo',$reqcommi);
            $bind = array('commType', 'out');
            $this->db->where_in('commType', $bind);
            
            $result = $this->db->get('agent_commission_history')->row();
            
            return $result->amount;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want retrieve data by post value USERID. And also show the individual 'contributions'.

What i'm seeing in your implementation, is that your summing all contributions by USERID 1 for example, but not grouping the values by individual contributors or retrieving the individual contributor values.

Group by agent example:

```
function gettotalcommi(){    
    return $this->db->select_sum('amount')
        ->from('agent_commission_history')
        ->where('commTo', $this->session->userdata('uid'))
        ->where_in('commType', ['commType', 'in'])
        ->group_by('commFrom')
        ->get()->row()->amount;
}
```

Individual get:

```
function gettotalcommi(){    
    return $this->db->select_sum('amount')
        ->from('agent_commission_history')
        ->where('commTo', $this->session->userdata('uid'))
        // individual 
        ->where('commFrom', $this->input->post('userID'))
        ->where_in('commType', ['commType', 'in'])
        ->get()->row()->amount;
}
```

I hope this helps. If i'm misinterpreting your question, lemme know.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping. However, i tried yours and it is not working. Additionally, My target is to get the commission of these users. The $reqcommi= $this->session->userdata('uid'); has no use in table. I just want to get the commission per user. Thank you so much. https://prnt.sc/10dj63u

Comment: Ah right. If you want the values of the invididual users, then you might need to run them their individual queries. Because the only query you're running atm is based on the logged in user. If you foreach the found users in the controller, you can add the values there and don't need to calculate in the view.